# How do I use Index & Match to reference a separate sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match

Background:

I have the following test code that is working where column H is equal to what's in column B versus column D

```
Range("H2:H17") = "=INDEX(D2:D17,MATCH(B2:B17,B2:B17,0))"
```

[image: temp1]

Question:

How do I use this in code to reference a separate sheet called "temp" to do the same thing.  The idea is for each time the code looks for 'target' it does
an index and match checking column B to equal what's in column D so if the valuue A is passed then it would become Test1?

I tried the following code, but target is not getting updated with any value.

Dim Target As Variant

```
With Application
    Target = .Index(Sheets("Temp").Range("D2:D17"), .Match(Sheets("Temp").Range("B2:B17"), Sheets("Temp").Range("B2:B17"), 0))
End With
```

Debugging shows the following for Target

[image: TargetWatch]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match`.

Comment: `Match` is a `WorksheetFunction` just like `Index`, and needs to be qualified the same way; `Sheets` is pulling sheets (including `Chart` sheets) from whatever workbook is currently active. Prefer pulling the worksheets you're working with, into `Worksheet` variables so you don't need to re-fetch the object reference every single time you need a range from that sheet (and pull them off the `Worksheets` collection ;-)

Comment: @BigBen plot twist: the early-bound version doesn't take an array (/range) for a lookup value!

Answer (score 1):

`Match` is a member of the `WorksheetFunction` interface; you need a `WorksheetFunction` object instance to invoke it off of - a `With` block could hold that object reference for you so you only need to type it once:

```
With Application.WorksheetFunction
    Target = .Index(sheet.Range("D2:D17"), .Match(sheet.Range("B2:B17"), sheet.Range("B2:B17"), 0))
End With
```

Where `sheet` would be a `Worksheet` variable to work with, or a `Worksheet` parameter to your procedure.

Something looks wrong with the first argument to `Match` though: `lookup_value` wants to be a single value: the early-bound `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` method is rather picky about what `Variant` subtypes it's willing to play along with nicely, and will throw a *type mismatch* error as-is.

The late-bound version (watch out for typos! `Option Explicit` can't save you from late-bound code!) works as expected with the range/array lookup value argument, and yields a `Variant()` array:

```
With Application
    Target = .Index(sheet.Range("D2:D17"), .Match(sheet.Range("B2:B17"), sheet.Range("B2:B17"), 0))
End With
```

Make sure `Target` is a `Variant`, because this late-bound `Match` will yield a `Variant/Error` value if the lookup fails (the early-bound version raises a run-time error instead) - and that'll be a *type mismatch* error if you try to assign to anything but a `Variant`.

Comment: Thanks Mathieu and Ben!  I followed suggestions and getting the exact error you mentioned "Run-Time error '13' Type mismatch"  so maybe the issue is related to what was first said since this is referencing "temp" which is an array?

Comment: And you're using the late-bound version?

Comment: I'm on Excel 15.0 and it looks like it's part of Office 2013

Comment: That was not the question. I'm giving you two versions of the `Match` function. One is early-bound (that's `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match`), the other is late-bound (that's `Application.Match`). You need to use the late-bound version, for the reasons explained in this answer.

Comment: Switched to the late bound version, the code now runs, but the values are blank. I made sure that target is set as variant at top of the code, for the test set Target = "A", but after running through the index match the values are showing as blank with notes updated above. Would it matter that the actual input data is string in order to accomodate for preceding zeros in number letter combinations?  The Test I'm running is just using a 7 digit number.